# Popover hint for imageview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, popover

Please take a look at image. 
I am littile bit confused how to implement this pop over view on an Image view. Actually the design is an stepper module. so once the user choose an option, the layout showing next step. So each step should have an Image View. I implemented the stepper layout, but have some confusion on how to set the popover on each steps. ie just below to the imageview.

**generated dynamic image view for showing steps.**

```
  for (int i = 0; i < CreationData.size(); i++) {
            imageContainer[i] = new ImageView(getContext());
            imageContainer[i].setImageResource(getResId(i, 0));// 0 determines the state of the image icon.
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
            imageContainer[i].setLayoutParams(param);

            dividerLine[i] = new View(getContext());
            dividerLine[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.stepper_line_color));       
        }
```

[image]. 
**Next I want to append the pop over to each image view**

Comment: Welcome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you must have to do some work pls show your efforts 

Comment: Sorry for the mistake happened. Actually I searched in web how to implement this popover. but I didn't get any idea.

Comment: @varshajeevan did you see my answwer?

Comment: sorry, I searched too  much finally I got a way to use Tooltip library, which is available in android, so I used one of them

Comment: Thank you all for the help  :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `setOnLongClickListener` on the ImageView help you:

```
myImageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Text to show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

In the xml set the ImageView long-clickable:

```
<ImageButton 
    ...
     android:longClickable="true"
/>
```

Or you can do the same via code:

```
myImageView.setLongClickable(true);
```